# How to load partial view

Tags: mvc-forms

I'm new to MVC. Trying to load a partial view but get a 500 error in browser console.

After clicking on submit, the action method is triggered and the code is executed without any errors.

I would like to replace the content of `myform` with a partial view, but there is an error in the browser console.

Do I need to configure any routes. If so, please tell me what/how it should be.

Using Sitecore 8.0.

**main.cshtml**

```
<div id="myform">
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ResetPassword", "Member", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myform", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
 {
    .....
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
 }
</div>
```

**controller**

```
[HttpPost]        
public ActionResult ResetPassword()
{
  ....
  return PartialView("~/Views/success.cshtml");
}
```

**success.cshtml**

```
@
{
 var contextItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
}
<div>
  <h3>Your password has been updated.</h3>
  <p>@contextItem.Fields[<id>].Value</p>
</div>
```

**Error:**

> POST http://mysite.org/api/sitecore/Member/ResetPassword
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

**Stack Trace**

```
> 25812 19:45:17 ERROR Application error. Exception:
> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException Message: An unhandled exception
> occurred. Source: Sitecore.Mvc    at
> Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext
> exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)    at
> Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs
> args)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
> Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
> Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String
> pipelineName, TArgs args)    at
> Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext
> exceptionContext)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext
> controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
> controllerContext, String actionName)    at
> Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
> controllerContext, String actionName)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass22.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1e()
> at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<.cctor>b__0(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult, Action action)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)   
> at
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult)    at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
> at
> Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
> result)    at
> System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
> Boolean& completedSynchronously)
> 
> Nested Exception
> 
> Exception: System.NullReferenceException Message: Object reference not
> set to an instance of an object. Source: App_Web_fel0uk2b    at
> ASP._Page_Views_ResetPassword_cshtml.Execute() in
> c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite.org\Website\Views\ResetPassword.cshtml:line
> 7    at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()    at
> System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()    at
> System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
> pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
> at
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
> filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
> ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
> filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
> ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
> filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
> ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
> controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
> controllerContext, String actionName)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the stacktrace

Comment: @HishaamNamooya I just did. Please check

Comment: Can you please provide the `Execute` method code please since the error is occurring in this which seems to be triggered from line 7 in the `ResetPassword.cshtml`

Comment: I have updated my question. The issue is with the variable `contextItem` in the partial view which is null. Is this by default, that in partial views, we cannot get the Sitecore Context Item? If so, then I have to create an exclusive model for this partial view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't submit an MVC form in the standard MVC way when using Sitecore. You have to do some specific things.

#### Method 1: Sitecore().FormHandler

First, your razor view needs to change from using `Ajax.BeginForm` to `Html.BeginRouteForm` and then passing in the Sitecore route name. Like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm(Sitecore.Mvc.Configuration.MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, FormMethod.Post))
{       
    @Html.Sitecore().FormHandler("Member", "ResetPassword") 

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Also note the `FormHandler` addition. That specifies the controller and action used when submitting the form.

With this method, you can redirect to another page after submission. But can't return a view or partial view.

#### Method 2: Pure MVC

There is another option that uses pure MVC to submit the form. In this option you would create your form `cshtml` like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="hidden" name="fhController" value="Member"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="fhAction" value="ResetPassword"/>

    <input type="submit" value="submit"/> 
}
```

Notice that here we have put the controller and action into hidden fields that will be submitted. This is because on a submit, Sitecore will hit all the controllers that are renderings on the page.

To find the correct POST action. We can use an attribute on the form handler action.

```
public class ValidateFormHandler : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var controller = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["fhController"];
        var action = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["fhAction"];

        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controller)
                && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(action)
                && controller == controllerContext.Controller.GetType().Name
                && methodInfo.Name == action;
    }
}
```

Then add the attribute to your post action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateFormHandler]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(FormModel model)
{
    // code
}
```

#### Method 3: Roll your own Ajax call

Finally - as it looks like you want to make this an ajax request, you could just register your controller action as a route to be used by a `$.ajax` call.

Add a pipeline process to the `Initialize` pipeline that will register your route:

```
public class RegisterRoutes
{
    public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("ResetPassword", "Member/ResetPassword", 
            new { controller = "Member", action = "ResetPassword" });
    }
}
```

Now you can make an ajax post from JavaScript to the url `/member/resetpassword` and handle the response to update your screen.

Credits for options 1 & 2 to Martina & Kevin:

- https://mhwelander.net/2014/05/28/posting-forms-in-sitecore-mvc-part-1-view-renderings/
- https://mhwelander.net/2014/05/30/posting-forms-in-sitecore-mvc-part-2-controller-renderings/
- https://ctor.io/posting-forms-in-sitecore-controller-renderings-another-perspective/

Comment: Thank you. Two Questions. (1) In my `Ajax.BeginForm()`, I have mentioned the controller & action names. Will this still hit all controllers. (2) All the above methods are standards for making a post in Sitecore and not loading a partial view. So, seems we cannot load a partial view like in MVC..is this right

Comment: You _should_ be able to use the `Ajax.BeginForm` like the `Html.BeginForm` - but you will want to use the `AjaxOptions` and give it an `OnSuccess` function to call when it has finished. Then handle the display that way. It wont just load in a partial view. Have a look at this for an example: http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/script/using-ajax-beginform-with-asp-net-mvc